# Javascript Audio object play/pause

Tags: javascript

I have theres function 1 is for playing music and the second is for set pause to the actual music, my pause function don't work. How can i do for set pause ?

```
function play(id){
        var audio = new Audio('music/'+id+'.mp3');
        audio.play();
}

function pause(){
        audio.pause();
}
```

Comment: Don't create the audio inside play. It won't be accessible by pause.

Comment: yes, but i couldn't acces to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The audio variable isn't accessible in the Pause function. You need to pass it as a parameter or set it outside the function. This is just an example of how you can do it:

```
var audio;

function createAudio(id) {
    audio = new Audio('music/'+id+'.mp3');
    play();
}

function play(){
    audio.play();
}

function pause(){
    audio.pause();
}
```

Comment: but know how to resume ?

Comment: I have edited the code. You can start and resume the sound by calling `play()`